# These if statements and for loops don't work

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, equals

I have this problem with this code.

data is an observableArrayList and holds a double array of strings called table. 
tempTable is another doublearray of strings with the same format as the tables in data.
Im trying to add tempTable to data only if there is not already a table in data that is equal to the table I am trying to add but for some reason it will only add if data is not empty and when it adds it add both if there is an existing table or if there is not an existing table in data.

I do not get any errors from runnning this.

**EDIT** I made the code easier to read

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  int p = data.size();
  Table tempTable = new Table(Integer.parseInt(s[i][0]), s[i][1], s[i][2], s[i][3], s[i][4], s[i][5], s[i][6], s[i][7], s[i][8], s[i][9], s[i][10], s[i][11], s[i][12], s[i][13], s[i][14], s[i][15], s[i][16]);
  for (int j = 0; j < p; j++){
    if (!data.get(j).equals(tempTable)){
      data.add(tempTable);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 things: no indentation, missing brackets

Comment: Do you have `equals` defined for your `Table` class?  Regardless of what data you store in it, Java is only going to look at `equals` when you're doing operations like that.

Comment: Suppose `data` contain 1, 10, 2 and `tempTable` contains 1, 20, 10. What should the result be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your logic backwards :

```
for (int j = 0; j < p; j++){
  if (!data.get(j).equals(tempTable)){
    data.add(tempTable);
    break;
  }
}
```

This will add `tempTable` if any of the elements in `data` is not equal to `tempTable`. You want to add it only if **all** the elements are not equal :

```
boolean found = false;
for (int j = 0; j < p; j++){
  if (data.get(j).equals(tempTable)){
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!found)
  data.add(tempTable);
```

Comment: No because the way I did it it will add all elements that are unique but skip all the elements that are nonUnique. The problem is that it still doesn't compare. Is there another way than using equals?

Comment: @Tilion No, that isn't what happens.  Suppose `data` has 2 elements that are different.  Now you set up a `tempTable` that is equal to `data.get(0)`.  I think your plan is not to add it since it's equal to `data.get(0)`.  However, when `j` is 1, `!data.get(j).equals(tempTable)` is `true` (since `tempTable` is equal to `data.get(0)` but not `data.get(1)`), so your original code adds it again.  Basically, your logic isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thank you. We tried comparing only the value of the integer that is frist in the array and the interger that is first of every array in the observableArrayList and now it works. Thank you